# How to create a custom report using jq?

Tags: bash, jq

What is the easiest way to take the json output of a curl statement and save variables created by filters in jq with the goal of creating a report (e.g., using javascript)? I love jq.play and can create filters to get firstname, lastname, etc. but want to use these results in a combined custom report and dont know how to save them to invidual variables from the shell.

Comment: Sorry for the fuzzy question. I have trying to output firstname lastname for each row in the json file.   here is the firstname: jq '.data[0].candidate.firstName' ./data.json so how do I create an output file with firstname and lastname?

Comment: That is, do I generate a file that does ">" and ">>" using -r and run this somehow in the shell?

Comment: Maybe something like the following but the blank is not working. Any suggestions?    import os
os.system("jq -r -j '.data[0].candidate.firstName' ./data.json >  myfile.txt")
os.system("printf '%s' " >>  myfile.txt")
os.system("jq -r -j '.data[0].candidate.lastName' ./data.json >>  myfile.txt")

Comment: Please edit your question itself instead of posting updates in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit fuzzy, but since you mention "the shell", the following might be relevant.  The *-r* option might also be relevant.

```
#!/bin/bash

vars=($(jq -n '"a\tb", "{\"a\":1}" | @sh'))

for x in "${vars[@]}"
do
  echo "$x"
done
```

The above script, when run, produces:

```
"'a\tb'"
"'{\"a\":1}'"
```

Here's a variant (and more dangerous) approach that uses *eval*:

```
jq -r '@sh "a=\(.a) b=\(.b)"' | while read -r line; do eval "$line"; done
```

You might also be able to do more of the processing in jq, so that (for example) you can create a pipeline, rather than setting shell variables.